# Sendmail process failed with error code 67

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, sendmail

Everything was worked fine but someday sendmail stop working on me.

I'am trying the following command line:

```
echo "Body text" | mail -s "Some subject" example@somemail.com
```

And got:

```
/home/<username>/dead.letter... Saved message in /home/<username>/dead.letter
Can't send mail: sendmail process failed with error code 67
```

How to fix that?

Comment: Try using mailx over mail.

Comment: @mdpc can you explain what does it mean please?

Comment: can you cut'n'paste the output from command "echo TEST|sendmail -v address@domain.com"

Comment: @silencedhaven it looks like so: http://pastebin.com/tt0GDMNi

Answer (score 5):

Your local MTA thinks that mail for whatever domain you tried to send to should be sent to the local machine, but there is no user with that username on the local machine. Ensure that the server's hostname is not the same as the domain name you are trying to deliver to, and that sendmail is not configured to deliver mail for that domain locally.

Comment: Actually, I'm trying to send some logs into my `gmail` account. And my hostname not a `gmail`. Also I checked /etc/hosts file and there system defaults, so there no alias to gmail too.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Way too late for this answer I'm sure, but I'll add my experience here since the answer is still somewhat unclear.

Error 67 is defined in `/usr/include/sysexits.h` as :

```
#define EX_NOUSER       67      /* addressee unknown */
```

Which made sense in my case because I was trying to send mail from `my-domain` to `user@my-domain`, so `sendmail` was looking for a local user on that system to send the mail to. 
The solution I wound up going with was to add `user` to `/etc/aliases` with an address that was *not* `@my-domain`

This fixed the issue no problem.